# Android run time error stating that unable find in manifesto file but I it was added

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-graphview

Hi I am trying to run an android app. Where my goal was to display a radar graph based on user preferences for that I have used the webview and sending the username to php file.

But Now I was getting an error stating that **"java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.newairways/com.example.newairways.communication}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.newairways.communication cannot be cast to android.app.Activity"**
I Have tried my level best to solve this but I could able to it. and in error it was stated the communication class was not mentioned So I have also mentioned but I required the radar part to display. So Please help me in solving this.

Here is my logcat

```
08-04 19:59:21.861: D/gralloc_goldfish(654): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
08-04 19:59:22.071: W/TextLayoutCache(654): computeValuesWithHarfbuzz -- need to force to single run
08-04 19:59:32.541: D/dalvikvm(654): GC_CONCURRENT freed 177K, 3% free 14296K/14599K, paused 7ms+7ms
08-04 19:59:36.962: W/TextLayoutCache(654): computeValuesWithHarfbuzz -- need to force to single run
08-04 19:59:45.762: W/SingleClientConnManager(654): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
08-04 19:59:45.762: W/SingleClientConnManager(654): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
08-04 19:59:45.811: I/System.out(654): Response : User Found
08-04 19:59:45.811: I/System.out(654): ---IF---
08-04 19:59:46.682: D/dalvikvm(654): GC_CONCURRENT freed 214K, 3% free 14607K/14919K, paused 6ms+8ms
08-04 19:59:46.831: D/dalvikvm(654): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 13K, 2% free 14946K/15239K, paused 52ms
08-04 19:59:50.781: D/AndroidRuntime(654): Shutting down VM
08-04 19:59:50.781: W/dalvikvm(654): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
08-04 19:59:50.831: E/AndroidRuntime(654): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-04 19:59:50.831: E/AndroidRuntime(654): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.newairways/com.example.newairways.communication}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.newairways.communication cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
08-04 19:59:50.831: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1879)
08-04 19:59:50.831: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
08-04 19:59:50.831: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
08-04 19:59:50.831: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
08-04 19:59:50.831: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-04 19:59:50.831: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-04 19:59:50.831: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
08-04 19:59:50.831: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-04 19:59:50.831: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-04 19:59:50.831: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-04 19:59:50.831: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-04 19:59:50.831: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-04 19:59:50.831: E/AndroidRuntime(654): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.newairways.communication cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
08-04 19:59:50.831: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
08-04 19:59:50.831: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1870)
08-04 19:59:50.831: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  ... 11 more
08-04 20:06:29.651: D/gralloc_goldfish(707): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
08-04 20:06:29.802: W/TextLayoutCache(707): computeValuesWithHarfbuzz -- need to force to single run
08-04 20:06:35.271: D/dalvikvm(707): GC_CONCURRENT freed 133K, 2% free 14335K/14599K, paused 7ms+6ms
08-04 20:06:47.093: W/TextLayoutCache(707): computeValuesWithHarfbuzz -- need to force to single run
08-04 20:06:55.241: W/SingleClientConnManager(707): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
08-04 20:06:55.241: W/SingleClientConnManager(707): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
08-04 20:06:55.352: D/dalvikvm(707): GC_CONCURRENT freed 298K, 3% free 14484K/14855K, paused 6ms+8ms
08-04 20:06:55.441: I/System.out(707): Response : User Found
08-04 20:06:55.512: I/System.out(707): ---IF---
08-04 20:06:56.211: D/dalvikvm(707): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 70K, 3% free 14754K/15111K, paused 46ms
08-04 20:06:56.334: D/dalvikvm(707): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 3% free 15023K/15367K, paused 50ms
08-04 20:07:00.851: D/AndroidRuntime(707): Shutting down VM
08-04 20:07:00.851: W/dalvikvm(707): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
08-04 20:07:00.901: E/AndroidRuntime(707): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-04 20:07:00.901: E/AndroidRuntime(707): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.newairways/com.example.newairways.communication}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.newairways.communication cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
08-04 20:07:00.901: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1879)
08-04 20:07:00.901: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
08-04 20:07:00.901: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
08-04 20:07:00.901: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
08-04 20:07:00.901: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-04 20:07:00.901: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-04 20:07:00.901: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
08-04 20:07:00.901: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-04 20:07:00.901: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-04 20:07:00.901: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-04 20:07:00.901: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-04 20:07:00.901: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-04 20:07:00.901: E/AndroidRuntime(707): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.newairways.communication cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
08-04 20:07:00.901: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
08-04 20:07:00.901: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1870)
08-04 20:07:00.901: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  ... 11 more
```

Here is my manifesto file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.newairways"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
       <activity
            android:name="com.example.newairways.login"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name="com.example.newairways.menu"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>s

       <activity
            android:name="com.example.newairways.bar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name="com.example.newairways.radar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.newairways.measure"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name="com.example.newairways.plan"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name="com.example.newairways.day0"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>

         <activity
            android:name="com.example.newairways.goaltest"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >


        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name="com.example.newairways.relationship"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>
                 <activity
            android:name="com.example.newairways.start"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>
                 <activity
            android:name="com.example.newairways.discipline"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>
                  <activity
            android:name="com.example.newairways.skills"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>
                 <activity
            android:name="com.example.newairways.knowledge"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>

                 <activity
            android:name="com.example.newairways.emotions"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>
                         <activity
            android:name="com.example.newairways.adaptation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>
                         <activity
            android:name="com.example.newairways.leadership"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>
                         <activity
            android:name="com.example.newairways.lifequality"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>

                         <activity
            android:name="com.example.newairways.Globalvars"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>

         <activity
            android:name="com.example.newairways.communication"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>
    </application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Please show the manifest and the declaration for com.example.newairways.communication

Comment: I have added the manifest file and I am not using the communications now it was a dummy one prestly I am looking for radar file to get it work.

Answer (score 0):

Does your activity extend android.app.activity ? Is the activity mentioned in the manifest file. Is the base package and fully qualified name of the activity class correct??

Comment: Yes I recheck it also But I could not able to succeed it.

Comment: I solved my problem It was an error while communicating I got it working. Thank your response.